# Norm of a full rank matrix and its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

If A is p × q with rank q, prove that $||\ A(A^TA)^{−1}A^T ||\ _2 = 1$. What does $A(A^T A)^{−1}A^T$ represent?

Answer (score 1):

Define $P=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^{T}$. There are multiple important concepts at play here. I recommend you study them on your own with the following couple of hints.

Hints:

- Is $A^TA$ invertible?
- What is $P^2$
- What is the nature of eigenvalues of $P$
- Is $P$ symmetric
- What are orthogonal projection matrices?
- Can you extend the above concepts to argue that every $x$ can be split as two vectors such that $x=u+v$ where $u=Px$ and $v=(I-P)x$. What is the inner product of $u$ and $v$ in this case.
- $||P||_2=\max_{||x||_2=1}||Px||_2$. Can you use all information above to calculate this now.